# Creating A new column based on other columns' values with specific requirement in Python Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I want to create a new column in Python dataframe with specific requirements from other columns. For example, my python dataframe df:

```
A    |    B    
-----------
5    |    0
5    |    1
15   |    1
10   |    1
10   |    1
20   |    2
15   |    2
10   |    2
5    |    3
15   |    3
10   |    4
20   |    0
```

I want to create new column C, with below requirements:

1. When the value of B = 0, then C = 0
2. The same value in B will have the same value in C. The same values in B will be classified as start, middle, and end. So for values 1, it has 1 start, 2 middle, and 1 end, for values 3, it has 1 start, 0 middle, and 1 end. And the calculation for each section:

I specify a **threshold = 10**.
Let's look at values B = 1 :

```
Start :
C.loc[2] = min(threshold, A.loc[1]) + A.loc[2]

Middle :
C.loc[3] = A.loc[3]
C.loc[4] = A.loc[4]

End:
C.loc[5] = min(Threshold, A.loc[6])
```

However, the output value of C will be the sum of the above calculations.

3. When the value of B is unique and not 0. For example when B = 4

   C[10] = min(threshold, A.loc[9]) + min(threshold, A.loc[11])

I can solve point 0 and 3. But I'm struggling to solve point 2.

So, the final output will be:

```
A   |    B    |   c
--------------------
5   |    0    |    0
5   |    1    |    45
15  |    1    |    45
10  |    1    |    45
10  |    1    |    45
20  |    2    |    50
15  |    2    |    50
10  |    2    |    50
5   |    3    |    25
10  |    3    |    25
10  |    4    |    20
20  |    0    |     0
```

Comment: is your final output expectation different from your logic?

Comment: Yes, for point2. I can not get the right logic for point 2.